# Lodash Merge - How come the 'source key' is ignored in both these cases?

Tags: javascript, lodash

As per the code example below - I have two objects, a source and a destination. The `files` property in the object is an array of objects. I cannot find a way using 'merge' from Lodash to get the output to have the source key.

```
import merge from 'lodash/merge';

const source = {files: [{key: 'Custom source key'}]};
const destination = {files: [{key: 'target key', foo: 'bar'}]};

merge( source, destination ); // {files: [{key: 'target key', foo: 'bar'}]};
merge( destination, source ); // {files: [{key: 'target key', foo: 'bar'}]};
```

https://codeclip.io/wmDyZi6T

I understand that order matters, so I would have assumed that one of the two scenarios would resolve in the 'custom source key' in the final object while the second to be the 'target key'.

Where am I going wrong?

TIA!

Ps - I have obviously over-simplified this example. The reason for using merge (vs vanilla JS) is that the actual source and destination objects are much more complex and many layers deep.

Comment: Don't use an image and a link to display your code in the question. Always inline your code or use a snippet. I've updated your question to include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash's `_.merge()` mutates the object passed as the 1st argument, and also returns it as the result of calling the function.

When you use `merge(source, destination)`, you mutate `source` by merging `destination` into it, and overwriting all the keys in `source` by those of `destination`.

In this example you can see that `source` has changed:

```js
const { merge } = _;

const source = {files: [{key: 'Custom source key'}]};
const destination = { files: [{ key: 'target key', foo: 'bar' }]};

merge(source, destination);

console.log(source); // source has changed
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Use an empty object `{}` as the merge target to avoid mutating the original objects:

```js
const { merge } = _;

const source = {files: [{key: 'Custom source key'}]};
const destination = { files: [{ key: 'target key', foo: 'bar' }]};

console.log(merge({}, source, destination));
console.log(merge({}, destination, source));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```